# /lib/udev/write_net_rules : No such file or directory

Tags: networking, udev

Let me quickly introduce my issue: I was trying to create a virtual IP address on my Linux by using the ifconfig instruction:

```
fconfig eth0:0 122.122.22.22
```

It gaves me the following error:

```
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0:0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

After some investigations, I found that is because the following file is missing: *70-persistent-net.rules*. It is supposed to be found in the following repertory: `/etc/udev/rules.d'`

So I made other investigations and it appears that this file is supposed to be automatically created at launch with the help of the following file `/lib/udev/write_net_rules` (among others). But once again, it appears that this file doesn't exist.

I made a lot of searching but I didn't find any good answer of why this specific file is missing. I tried to reset Udev by using several instruction but noting works. Is anyone here have a solution?

Thanks a lot :).

Comment: Crossposted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160407/lib-udev-write-net-rules-is-missing

Comment: Are you sure that your interface is named `eth0`? that seems unlikely on any recent Ubuntu version - unless you have taken steps to disable predictable interface naming?)

Comment: To be honest I just followed some tutorials. Maybe it exist other solution but didn't find it.

Comment: I suggest you start by determining what your interface name actually is (either by running `ifconfig -a`, or `ls /sys/class/net`)

Comment: It gives me this answer : `enp1s0  lo  wlp2s0`

Comment: So you need to modify the command accordingly e.g. `ifconfig enp1s0:0 122.122.22.22` (you will likely need to be root to do this)